# rails delete_if using hashes to ignore current article (Middleman)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman, contentful

I've got an easy one for you guys.

**I want to have a featured content section where the current article is EXCLUDED**

So this works using Middleman Blog with `delete_if`:

```
<% blog(content).articles.delete_if{|item| item == current_article}.each do |article| %>
  <%= article_content %>
<% end %>
```

However I'm using Middleman proxies so I don't have access to the `current_article` method...

I've got an YAML structure that holds the following mock data (amongst others) with the folder setup like: **data > site > caseStudy > RANDOM-ID423536.yaml** (Generated by a CMS)

[image]

Inside each `yaml` file you'll find stuff like:

```
:id: 2k1YccJrQsKE2siSO6o6ac
:title: Heyplace
```

My `config.rb` looks like this

```
data.site.caseStudy.each do | id, this |
  proxy "/cases/#{this.slug}/index.html", "/cases/cases-template.html", :locals => { this: this }, :ignore => true
end
```

My template file holds the following

```
<%= partial(:'partials/footer', :locals => {:content => data.site.caseStudy, :title => 'See more projects'}) %>
```

My loop that gets content

```
<% content.each do |id, this| %>
  <%= partial "partials/tile" %>
<% end %>
```

**So I guess my question is, how can I use `delete_if` in this instance so that the current article isnt being displayed?**

I have tried stuff like, but to no avail:

```
<% content.delete_if{|e| e.title == content.title}.each do |id, this| %>
  <%= partial "partials/tile" %>
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Solved, ended up doing

```
<% content.reject{ | id, item| item == this }.each do |id, this| %>
<%= partial "partials/tile", :locals => { :this => this, :dir => "/#{this.content_type_id.downcase}/", :secondary => 'View' } %>
<% end %>
```

Courtesy of @David Litvak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of contentful_middleman. Looks like you could just send the `this` to the partial as local, then iterate through your content and make sure that you exclude the one that matches the id of `this`.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking your time to help me. Do you know roughly how I would do that with hashes (from contentful)? I'm not super familiar with how to do that. With arrays it's a bit easier

Comment: The following kind of worked, but now they are getting deleted in the cache. I have to reload the page a couple of times to get the tiles to reappear. Very strange 

`<% content.reject{|key, value| key >= this.id }.sort_by{ |index| rand }.each do |id, this| %>
      <%= partial "partials/tile" %>
    <% end %>`